# Opening Access Forms and Referencing Fields

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm trying to load a form in Access in order to get field data from it and store that field text into a variable. I want to transfer it to Microsoft Word (but that's another problem for a different day).

This code goes in the Access Object and it's subroutine is referenced in the modules section

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "ContactDetails"
Dim NameBoxOne As String
NameBoxOne = Forms!ContactDetails!txtFirstName.Value
```

I receive:

> Run Time Error -2146500594 (800f000e)
>  Method 'Item' of object 'Forms' failed when trying to reference a field.

I suspect this is the case because the form hasn't completely loaded after opening, but that is only a guess.

Comment: What event is code in? Is it behind ContactDetails? Is txtFirstName name of field or textbox? I name controls different from fields, such as tbxFN for textbox. Edit question with additional info.

Comment: That is a clumsy way to get the data! Where does the form gets the data from? From the tables/queries! So why take the detour when you can get the data from a table/query easy with a`Dlookup`.Just use the forms Record Source as query.

Comment: Question edit shows code is all behind first form. Why does first form need to pull value from form it opens and why from first record? I tested code in button Click on first form and it works, no error.

Comment: Your code contains error somewhere, that prevents it from execute properly! Try to compile database in vba-ide Debug->Compile Database. Correct all errors, maybe you have to check Tools->References too. After that code should work. Coincidentally I had the same problem when I tested your code, even if Form was allready open. After removing the errors and compile it worked.